# Prevent Xcode from opening new files

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to prevent Xcode from opening brand new files? Let me explain. Everytime I create a new file (Xib, .swift, .storyboard, etc...) Xcode opens that new file automatically in the standard editor. This functionality kinda annoys me because something I just want to create the file and maybe open it on the assistance editor instead or just to work on the file later. I tried changing some of the Xcode's behavior but I don't see any ways where I can trigger an action when certain events occur (like creating a new file).

Comment: Not really a fix, but it might improve your situation to know you can just click the back button or use the keyboard shortcut: `CMD` + `ctrl` + `<-` to go back to the previous file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here's one way:

Create a folder full of empty files of various types (with various extensions) that you typically create.  Then whenenver you want a new file, rather than telling Xcode to create a new file, use the **"Add Files to ..."** command and choose one of those files.  Just remember to also check the checkbox **"Copy items if needed"**.

Doing this won't open the added file.

As an added benefit, you could also make some versions of these files pre-seeded with code or comments or whatever else that you often keep re-typing into many of your new files.